# Tumblr Description <table>

Tags: html-table, tumblr

I'm writing some code that will go into the description box of a Tumblr page, in order to set a small tagline on the left of the header, and a search box of the right side of the same line. I've been trying to use a table with two cells and the width of the page to achieve this. However, it seems that the description box doesn't accept the `<table>` tag (it appears to work in the preview but not in the actual page).

Is there any other way to achieve inline content, with one  justified left and the other right?

Comment: Search for "liquid html layout". Table-layouts are *so* last century.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to include HTML elements in your Tumblr description.

There are two ways to achieve this:

1. Escape any HTML you are adding to the description box. This [tool](http://www.htmlescape.net/htmlescape_tool.html) can help.
2. Modify the themes HTML and take advantage of [Variable Transformations](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#variable-transformations). In this scenario the `{Description}` tag would be replaced with `{PlaintextDescription}`

Either method should allow you to add HTML elements.

Also, I would take the advice of the comment made above. There is no need to use a table for the layout your trying to achieve.